# Accept certificate permanently during FtpWebRequest via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, powershell-4.0

Recently I encounter some problems making the connection to a FTP server but there will be some popup asking for the acceptance on the certificate.

I don't know how to overcome this via PowerShell during invoke method `$ftpRequest.GetResponse()`. I found some solution regarding overriding the callback method on certificate like this one `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

The solution is given on C# &  I don't know how to port it to PowerShell yet.

My code is as below

```
function Create-FtpDirectory {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $sourceuri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $password
    )
    if ($sourceUri -match '\\$|\\\w+$') { throw 'sourceuri should end with a file name' }
    $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($sourceuri);    

    Write-Information -MessageData "Create folder  to store backup (Get-FolderName -Path $global:backupFolder)"
    $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
    $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true

    $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
    $ftprequest.EnableSsl = $true        

    $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();

    Write-Host "Folder created successfully, status $response.StatusDescription"

    $response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you can use raw C# in PowerShell via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type). Here's an example class I've used to be able to toggle certificate validation in the current PowerShell session.

```
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'CertValidation').Type)
{
    Add-Type @"
        using System.Net;
        using System.Net.Security;
        using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
        public class CertValidation
        {
            static bool IgnoreValidation(object o, X509Certificate c, X509Chain ch, SslPolicyErrors e) {
                return true;
            }
            public static void Ignore() {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = IgnoreValidation;
            }
            public static void Restore() {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = null;
            }
        }
"@
}
```

Then you can use it prior to calling your function like this.

```
[CertValidation]::Ignore()
```

And later, restore default cert validation like this.

```
[CertValidation]::Restore()
```

Keep in mind though that it's much safer to just fix your service's certificate so that validation actually succeeds. Ignoring certificate validation should be your last resort if you have no control over the environment.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I encountered this issue once in Java & I try to install the certificate properly manually instead of ignoring it like this. 
This totally should be the last resort based on the case you mentioned.
I got a problem while Add-Type, shouldn't it be a parameter set?

Comment: I need to declare a `$source` variable to store C# code & call the following command
`Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source`
Like the first example here from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-4.0)

Comment: You can choose to put the code into a string variable first if you want, but it's not required. `-TypeDefinition` is a positional parameter that takes a string. Whether that string is a variable reference or a [here-string](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) as in my example is irrelevant.

Comment: Then it's just weird to me that if I don't define a string variable first then it will throw exception during running & the method will not be said not to be found.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED] While searching for Invoke-RestRequest, I found this solution from Microsoft example

**Caution: this is actually accept ANY Certificate**

```
# Next, allow the use of self-signed SSL certificates.

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $True }
```

More information (thanks to @Nimral) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This does kind of work, but it should be noted, that this does not exactly make the client accept a self-signed server certificate, in fact it makes the client accept any certificate, effectively turning off server certificate checking. A better link: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Nimral Yep, you're right. I later found out but forgot to update on the result. Let me update a caution note on this one